# What do the first two characters in AL32UTF8 mean?

Tags: oracle

What does the "AL" in oracles' AL32UTF8 character set name mean or stand for?

I know it basically means UTF8 and I assume the 32 refers to the maximum number of bits used to encode a single character but I cannot find the meaning of the first two characters anywhere and I've been googling for about ten to fifteen minutes, running into all kinds of documentation that explain storage but not the name.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch2charset.htm#NLSPG169

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AL stands for All Languages

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/globalization/twp-appdev-unicode-10gr2-129234.pdf

page 8